# Story page hides privacy online status

Tags: support, feature-request, status-declined, developer-story

I want to customize my privacy - and hide my online status text "Last active on Stack Overflow today" on the "story page":

https://stackoverflow.com/story/bgbruno

In settings, "Update privacy" - checkboxes "Show the developer story tab" or "Always visible" do not have an effect on that obviously:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/storypreferences/1347601#privacy

How can I hide that information?

Comment: Even if there is a way to do what you want, the information will [still be available](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23148/323179) on your regular profile.

Comment: Well, this actually seems like a good feature request. Imagine a workplace where Stack Overflow is forbidden, but you were logged in on your phone during break time or on toilet visit, you could get in trouble for it.

Comment: Silly idea - make something that automatically pings SO with your credentials every semi-random X minutes, post publicly that you're using such a thing for privacy reasons, and then the last active text will not reveal any information (other than if your script is still running).

Comment: @CertainPerformance Proposing an alternative solution is no argument against this request, so currently you have brought no valid argument for your claim "silly idea"

Comment: @CertainPerformance "no valid argument" - I just ask how can I do that --- but why is easy - if that is story like CV that I think it's not chat or forum to show my additional info about my movement

Comment: @CertainPerformance ah I see - little bit messy in comments if I don't see threads :-)

Comment: @CertainPerformance, BGBruno, thx to you all that you stayed patient until we sorted out all our misunderstandings :-) m)

Comment: @akraf "Silly idea" was not directed at the OP's request here but simply acknowledging that the idea to follow (making the "last active" information useless) would be silly. CertainPerformance did not try to make an argument against anything.

Comment: Product was sunset so putting a status-declined tag here.